# Add current date as a spool file name in Oracle SQL Developer

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

I am trying to include the system date when spooling the file in Oracle SQL Developer. I found a solution similar to my problem. I copied the whole script I found but I am not getting the expected outcome.

I tried this solution from one of the resources but it didn't work:

```
set term off
set feed off
define x=date

column sd new_value x
select to_char(sysdate,'YYYYMMDD') sd from dual;

spool C:\projects\2024\spool\records_&x..txt

select * from TB_USERS;

spool off;
```

Upon running the script (F5), I am getting a records*&x.txt under the directory instead of records_20240124.txt. Is there a missing syntax or what could be the problem with my codes?*

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Unlike SQL*Plus, Oracle SQL Developer does not replace the substitution variable (`&x`) within the `spool` command. If so, you need to create the spool file name before executing the spool command.

```
set term off
set feed off
define x=date

column sd new_value x
select to_char(sysdate,'YYYYMMDD') sd from dual;

-- Create the spool file name
var spool_file varchar2(100);
exec :spool_file := 'C:\projects\2024\spool\records_' || :x || '.txt';

-- Now start spooling
spool &spool_file

select * from TB_USERS;

spool off;
```